# How do I configure the broker heartbeat in airflow so I can see the heartbeat in Connections tab in RMQ management UI?

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow

Currently using airflow 1.10.15 with CeleryExecutor and RabbitMQ as broker. I need to configure heartbeat so that in RMQ Management Connections tab, I can see the heartbeat value. I see heartbeat configuration in airflow.cfg but I think those are application level heartbeat. I need the configuration for RMQ. I think this is set to some default value by airflow but I am not seeing the value in the `Connections` tab. How can I set the broker heartbeat in airflow?

Update 9/14: Looks to me the airflow workers has a heartbeat (it got default of 60sec). But there are connections that I see that don't have a heartbeat. Is this because of the zoombie tasks(tasks/pods that airflow cannot tract anymore)? Also if I delete a connection, another one will be created with zero heartbeat which I suspect is created by airflow worker.